# Support Nullable fields in Google Cloud Dataflow coders

Tags: serialization, google-cloud-dataflow

*Google Cloud Dataflow* ships with a set of standard coders, which is great. However, none of them support `nulls` (inherently since `java.io.DataOutput` does not support `nulls`).

Just wondering, should one decorate each of the available coders, or maybe this had already been done somewhere?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Correct. The default coders for primitive types don't support null. [AvroCoder](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder) can support nulls if using @Nullable or Unions.

We can look into adding a coder that supports null. I've filed a feature request. Thanks!